# Get mongodb keys by using sails js

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, sails.js

```
mr = db.runCommand({ 
    "mapreduce" : "company",
    "map" : function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
    "out": "company" + "_keys"
})

db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

This is the query I'm using to get the keys from mongodb but how do I  convert this query to sails js code? Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`native()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)** method on your model to access the underlying Mongo collection then perform the raw Mongo queries like mapReduce. The following demonstrates this:

```
Company.native(function(err, companyCollection) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    // Map function
    var map = function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } };
    // Reduce function
    var reduce = function() { };
    // Other options
    var options = {out: {replace : 'company_keys'}};

    // Peform the map reduce
    // Mapreduce returns the company_keys collection with the results
    companyCollection.mapReduce(map, reduce, options, function(err, keysCollection) {
        // Perform a distinct query against the _id field of the keysCollection
        keysCollection.distinct("_id", function(err, results) {
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);
            console.log(results); // returns a list of the keys ['key1', 'key2', ...]

            return res.ok(results);        
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for gave  the solution  #chridam but using this code i am getting the error :"non_object_property_call
 message:   Cannot call method 'distinct' of undefined" ?

Comment: My requirement is to convert the result coming from the postman in to PDF format and want to download that file in sails.js. can any one give the solution?